# Responsive bootstrap not working on mobile in rails project

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I am using devise gem on Rails

If pressed the select form button form drop down overflow screen size, the select form is not working Properly please help me.

`views/registration/new.html.erb`

```
<div class="field">

    <%= f.label :Industry_Type %> : </b><br />
    <%= f.select :industry,options_for_select([["Select One", ""],
                                            'Automobiles & Transportions', 
                                            'Computer & Telecommunication', 
                                            'Electronics', 
                                            'Electrical']),{},
                                            {class: "form form-group form-control"}%>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your *output* HTML. The current code snippet is useless for debugging.

Comment: Agreed. Can you please expand upon " is not working Properly" - what do you observe? what do you expect to see instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the following, it's working properly

```
<%= f.select :industry, [["Select One", " "], 
                        ["Automobiles & Transportions"], 
                        ["Computer & Telecommunication"], 
                        ["Electronics"], ["Electrical" ]],{}, 
                        class: 'form form-group form-control'%>
```

genereted HTML code

```
<select class="form form-group form-control" name="user[industry]" id="user_industry">
    <option value=" ">Select One</option>
    <option value="Automobiles & Transportions">Automobiles & Transportions</option>
    <option value="Computer & Telecommunication">Computer & Telecommunication</option>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
</select>
```

**Edit After Question Update**

On top of the screen size when you use 100% then it will show properly you have to see with 45% change this 45% to 100%

Comment: Ohh! @adarsh it's not a problem, when you testing device using laptop or desktop then showing like you shared photo, but when you use really using various device like Samsung, iPhone, oppo etc.. then the like I have shared photo which is my answer

Comment: On the top when you use 100% then it will show properly you have to see with 45% change this 45% to 100%

Comment: Ok, I check with mobile, thanks for helping me with your answer